# I implemented an OCR program using python in Godot but it doesn't work when exported

Tags: python, export, ocr, tesseract, godot4

I implemented an OCR program using python in Godot but it doesn't work when exported. I created the python scripts in a virtual environment inside the Godot project folder. I exported the file for windows, but when I run it the OCR python script doesn't run. I then exported the project in a .zip file and saw the the python virtual environment has not been exported because Godot can't read that file. How do I make Godot export all the resources in the project folder?

I tried copying the python files from the original project folder into the exported zip file but it still didn't work.

Comment: What are you using to execute the python code?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm using the OS.execute function